# Erro "NoInitialContextException" ao subir aplicação GWT via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Estou tentando subir uma aplicação feita em GWT 2.4 no Eclipse Kepler (4.3), usando o Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Ao usar a opção `Run As > Web Application`, recebo imediatamente no log o erro abaixo:

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@19c0705{/,E:\projetos\_workspace\paymentmonitor\target\paymentmonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.createEnvContext(EnvConfiguration.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configureDefaults(EnvConfiguration.java:101)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1231)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após pesquisar sobre o erro, percebi que o mesmo ocorre nesse ambiente devido à ordem de carregamento das dependências no *classpath* da execução.

A solução foi acessar o menu `Run > Run Configurations...`, selecionar a respectiva configuração de execução, ir até a aba *Classpath* e mover a entrada relacionado ao GWT para o topo da lista.

Ordem das entradas que causa o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ordem das entradas que resolve o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Nota: encontrei informações detalhadas em uma [issue no Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4479) relacionada ao problema.*